# How to set QFileDialog to set initially selected files?

Tags: user-interface, qt

I mean when the Dialog pop up, some files according to the filer are in selected state.
Does QFileDialog has a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QFileDialog fd;
// Enable multple selection
fd.setFileMode( QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
// Select the files you need
fs.selectFile( "MyFirstFile");
fs.selectFile( "MySecondFile");
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
But there are mistakes and it should select multi file using following:

    QFileDialog fd;
    // Enable multple selection
    fd.setFileMode( QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
    // Select the files you need
    fd.selectFile( "\"main.cpp\" \"main.o\"");
    fd.exec();
    return;


By the way, how to place code in here like you?

Comment: When editing the question (or answer) you have some formatting buttons above the edit box. You can use them.