# Pre-select multiple files in a QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog, multipleselection

When a "choose files" dialog is displayed I want to pre-select files in a project which are already configured as being "part of" that project, so the user can select new files OR *unselect* existing (i.e. previously chosen) files.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3967099/595305) suggests multiple selection should be possible.

For this MRE, please make 3 files and put them in a suitable `ref_dir`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handle_button)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handle_button(self):
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        ref_dir = 'D:\\temp'
        files_list = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
        fd = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(None, 'Choose project files', ref_dir, '(*.txt)')
        fd.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
        fd.setOptions(options)
        # fd.setVisible(True)
        for file in files_list:
            print(f'selecting file |{file}|')
            fd.selectFile(file)
        string_list = fd.exec()
        print(f'string list {string_list}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Unfortunately, despite `ExistingFiles` having been chosen as the file mode, I find that it is only the last file selected which has the selection... but I want all three to be selected when the dialog is displayed.

I tried experimenting with `setVisible` to see whether the multiple selection could be achieved somehow after the dialog is displayed, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a non-native file dialog is being used, we can access its child widgets to control its behavior.

At first I thought about using the selection model of the item views, but this won't update the line edit, which is responsible of checking if the files exist and enabling the Ok button in that case; considering this, the obvious solution is to directly update the line edit instead:

```
    def handle_button(self):
        # ...
        existing = []
        for file in files_list:
            if fd.directory().exists(file):
                existing.append('"{}"'.format(file))
        lineEdit = fd.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'fileNameEdit')
        lineEdit.setText(' '.join(existing))
        if fd.exec():
            print('string list {}'.format(fd.selectedFiles()))
```

The only drawback of this approach is that the `fileSelected` and `filesSelected` signals are not sent.

Comment: Thanks. On the basis of your original idea I had got as far as finding that there are 3 `QItemSelectionModel`s in a `QFileDialog`, all of which have a `rowCount` of 2, even when you are showing 3 files, so not sure what's going on there. Some messing about with the "Choose" button to address the problem you mention might be possible, but this solution of yours is v. clever.

Comment: @mikerodent you shouldn't look for the selection model, but for the item views. Specifically, QFileDialog has two views used to show the files, a QListView and a QTreeView, accessible using `findChild` along with their object names (`listView` and `treeView`, respectively). Once you get the views, you can get their selection models (and they are synchronized, so it doesn't really matters which view you choose). Since you seem pretty interested in QFileDialog, I suggest you to study the source code: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp.html

Comment: Note that QFileDialog is one of the few Qt classes that also has a separate UI file, and you can find it here: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/.uic/ui_qfiledialog.h.html

Comment: I've in fact found that there is a fatal flaw with your (otherwise excellent) solution: with your solution it is impossible to effectively deselect the final selected file in a directory. See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Musicamante's answer was very, very helpful, in particular showing that the selection is in fact triggered by filling the QLE with path strings.

But in fact there is a fatal flaw when the purpose is as I have stated: unfortunately, if you try to deselect the final selected file in a directory, actually this name is *not* then removed from the QLE. And in fact, if the QLE is set to blank this disables the "Choose" button. All this is by design: the function of a `QFileDialog` is **either** to "open" or to "save", not to "modify".

But I did find a solution, which involves finding the `QListView` which lists the files in the directory, and then using a signal on its selection model.

Another thing this caters for is what happens when you change directory: obviously, you then want the selection to be updated on the basis of the project's files as found (or not found) inside that directory. I've in fact changed the text of the "choose" button to show that "modification" is the name of the game.

```
fd = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(app.get_main_window(), 'Modify project files', start_directory, '(*.docx)')
fd.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
fd.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.List)

fd.setLabelText(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Reject, '&Cancel')
fd.setLabelText(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Accept, '&Modify')
fd.setOptions(options)

file_name_line_edit = fd.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'fileNameEdit')
list_view = fd.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView, 'listView')

# utility to cope with all permutations of backslashes and forward slashes in path strings:
def split_file_path_str(path_str):
    dir_path_str, filename = ntpath.split(path_str)
    return dir_path_str, (filename or ntpath.basename(dir_path_str))

fd.displayed_dir = None
sel_model = list_view.selectionModel()
def sel_changed():
    if not fd.displayed_dir:
        return

    selected_file_paths_in_shown_dir = []
    sel_col_0s = sel_model.selectedRows()
    for sel_col_0 in sel_col_0s:
        file_path_str = os.path.join(fd.displayed_dir, sel_col_0.data())
        selected_file_paths_in_shown_dir.append(file_path_str)
        already_included = file_path_str in self.files_list
        if not already_included:
            fd.project_files_in_shown_dir.append(file_path_str)
            
    # now find if there are any project files which are now NOT selected
    for project_file_path_str in fd.project_files_in_shown_dir:
        if project_file_path_str not in selected_file_paths_in_shown_dir:
            fd.project_files_in_shown_dir.remove(project_file_path_str)
            
sel_model.selectionChanged.connect(sel_changed)

def file_dlg_dir_entered(displayed_dir):
    displayed_dir = os.path.normpath(displayed_dir)
    
    # this is set to None to prevent unwanted selection processing triggered by setText(...) below 
    fd.displayed_dir = None
    
    fd.project_files_in_shown_dir = []
    existing = []
    for file_path_str in self.files_list:
        dir_path_str, filename = split_file_path_str(file_path_str)
        if dir_path_str == displayed_dir:     
            existing.append(f'"{file_path_str}"')
            fd.project_files_in_shown_dir.append(file_path_str)
    file_name_line_edit.setText(' '.join(existing))            
    fd.displayed_dir = displayed_dir
    
fd.directoryEntered.connect(file_dlg_dir_entered)

# set the initially displayed directory...
file_dlg_dir_entered(start_directory)

if fd.exec():
    # for each file, if not present in self.files_list, add to files list and make self dirty
    for project_file_in_shown_dir in fd.project_files_in_shown_dir:
        if project_file_in_shown_dir not in self.files_list:
            self.files_list.append(project_file_in_shown_dir)
            # also add to list widget...
            app.get_main_window().ui.files_list.addItem(project_file_in_shown_dir)
            if not self.is_dirty():
                self.toggle_dirty()
    
    # but we also have to make sure that a file has not been UNselected...
    docx_files_in_start_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(fd.displayed_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(fd.displayed_dir, f)) and os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.docx' ]
    for docx_file_in_start_dir in docx_files_in_start_dir:
        docx_file_path_str = os.path.join(fd.displayed_dir, docx_file_in_start_dir)
        if docx_file_path_str in self.files_list and docx_file_path_str not in fd.project_files_in_shown_dir:
            self.files_list.remove(docx_file_path_str)
            list_widget = app.get_main_window().ui.files_list
            item_for_removal = list_widget.findItems(docx_file_path_str, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)[0]
            list_widget.takeItem(list_widget.row(item_for_removal))
            if not self.is_dirty():
                self.toggle_dirty()
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of playing around, here's a pretty good way to programatically pre-select multiple files in a QFileDialog:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5.QtCore import QItemSelectionModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QListView

p_files = Path('/path/to/your/files')

dlg = QFileDialog(
    directory=str(p_files),
    options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)

# get QListView which controls item selection
file_view = dlg.findChild(QListView, 'listView')

# filter files which we want to select based on any condition (eg only .txt files)
# anything will work here as long as you get a list of Path objects or just str filepaths
sel_files = [p for p in p_files.iterdir() if p.suffix == '.txt']

# get selection model (QItemSelectionModel)
sel_model = file_view.selectionModel()

for p in sel_files:

    # get idx (QModelIndex) from model() (QFileSystemModel) using str of Path obj
    idx = sel_model.model().index(str(p))

    # set the active selection using each QModelIndex
    # IMPORTANT - need to include the selection type
    # see dir(QItemSelectionModel) for all options
    sel_model.select(idx, QItemSelectionModel.Select | QItemSelectionModel.Rows)

dlg.exec_()

dlg.selectedFiles()
>>> ['list.txt', 'of.txt', 'selected.txt', 'files.txt']
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but the functionality also has to then be able to detect which files have been selected or deselected (i.e. had their selection toggled) by the user! My answer does that so I'm not sure your answer adds a great deal.

Comment: @mikerodent sorry I missed adding `| QItemSelectionModel.Rows` to the `select()` method which is required to allow QFileDialog to recognize the selected rows (not really sure why). Just tested again and seems to work fine for me now.

Comment: Only thing is this method still doesn't show the selected filenames in the text box, but I'm sure there's a way to add that in too, just wasn't super necessary for what I was doing.